# C# SQL create table with autonumber column

Tags: c#, sql

How can I create a table from SQL Command that will have a ID that is auto-number or auto-increment?

```
 SqlCommand com 
   = new SqlCommand("create table VeryCoolTable(\"Name\" nvarchar(50) 
      ,id AUTONUMBER)", con);
```

The counter is not recognized and I get error.

Comment: What version of SQL are you using? MSSQL uses IDENTITY.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you are using `SQL-Server` it is called `IDENTITY`

```
ID int IDENTITY(1,1)
```

**1.** first argument is the starting value
**2.** second argument is incrementing count

if you want to start the value from 500 and increment it by 5 
then try this:

```
ID int IDENTITY(500,5)
```

**Solution 1:**

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("create table VeryCoolTable(\"Name\"
                                    nvarchar(50),ID int IDENTITY(1,1))", con);
```

**Note:** i would suggest you to declare the ID column as `PRIMARY KEY` to identify the records in your table uniqly.

**Solution 2**

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("create table VeryCoolTable(\"Name\"
                     nvarchar(50),ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY)", con);
```

Comment: @Paul : it's my Privilege

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
)
```